# SQL Server 2012 - SA account probe

Tags: security, sql-server-2012, windows-server-2012, windows-firewall

On one of my servers (Win 2012 R2), SQL Server 2012 is constantly under attack with the SA account being tested like 10 times per second. I don't have an SA account but still I would like to stop this probing as its probably consuming resources. I keep checking the logs and blocking the offending IPs at firewall level manually, still I would like a better solution. SQL Server runs locally with IIS to serve its websites, I only need to connect to SQL Server remotely for database development with SSMS, so at first I thought placing a VPN but not sure if this is going to play well with SSMS and other services like FTP. As in interim solution where can I stop SQL Server from being visible to the outside world? At the firewall by disabling port 1433, or elsewhere? I can then enable/disable this when developing. Thanks.

Comment: This really doesn't have anything to do with **programming**, but with DB administration - so it's off-topic here and belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) - voting to move.

Comment: You are totally right, sorry my bad. Please move.

Comment: This question can be deleted, I already placed it on DBA. Thanks.